# Is it possible to ensure uniqueness at compile time for a function parameter value?

Tags: typescript

I have a static list of identifiers. I would like to "tag" a function call using one of these identifiers. I know I can do the following:

```
type Id = 'id-1' | 'id-2';

function foo(id : Id) {
  console.log(`my id: ${id}`);
}

foo('id-1');
foo('id-2');
```

But what I really want to happen is to see a type error if the same id is passed to the function:

```
type MagicId = /* some magic type to achieve uniqueness */;

function foo(id : MagicId) {
  console.log(`my id: ${id}`);
}

foo('id-1');
foo('id-1'); // type error is thrown
```

Comment: I believe doing this would require support for some kind of [_linear type_](https://wiki.c2.com/?LinearTypes)-like system, which TypeScript does not support (i.e. `type Id` values would become non-sharable).

Comment: Out of curiosity, what is the **actual** problem you're trying to solve here?

Comment: We have this tool at work to monitor feature degradation. We have to pass an identifier to tag these features. It would be useful to ensure that the function invocations are all identified uniquely so that duplication is avoided. For example, if someone copies code from one function to another, an error would be thrown effectively saying "Hey, you already used this identifier."

Comment: You'd be better-off implementing that as a static-analysis step rather than abusing the type-system for that: it'd be a simple TSLint tool: https://palantir.github.io/tslint/

Answer (score 3):

There is something to achieve this, but you have to relay on objects:

```
type Id = 'id-1' | 'id-2';

function _foo(id: Id) {
  console.log(`My id: ${id}`)
}

function foo<T extends Id>(id : T) {
  _foo(id);
  return {
    foo(id: Exclude<Id, T>) {
      _foo(id);
    }
  }
}

foo('id-1').foo('id-2'); // ok

foo('id-1').foo('id-1'); // error
```

As you can see the outer `foo` can accept both `"id-1"` and `"id-2"`, but the inner can't, since we `Exclude` the type of the outer foo.

This approach works if you have consecutive calls, othwerwise you have to save the result of the outer `foo` and assume you never call again the outer `foo`.

Here is a [playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAkgJlAvFA5ASzgWgIwqgH1Q0wCYUBuAKEoDMBXAOwGNg0B7BqAfRrbYAoMALlhwAlFADelKFCYcAzmwA2EAHTK2Ac34ADALIgowqABJJGAL66xlS9XrNWHKLzYAeACpQIAD2AQDHAKogB8ggginhLSsjx8EWJUsgBOEMB0KZyxsq4JXCYAor5MynRwEO7wADRQnqExMrlxbonJufay9va0CehYuGJqrf2kKElQAPSTUGwA1g59xIPDSwPj5FMzECkpbClAA).

An improved version would be the following:

```
type Builder<T> = {
  foo<I extends T>(id: I): Builder<Exclude<T, I>>;
};

const builder = {
  foo<T extends Id>(id: T): Builder<Exclude<Id, T>> {
    console.log(`My id ${id}`);
    return this;
  },
};

builder.foo("id-1").foo("id-2");
```

This is recursive and strip away the types we already used:

```
builder
  .foo("id-1") // ok, we can still have "id-2"
  .foo("id-2") // ok, we have finished the values, so the next one will be `never`
  .foo("id-1") // error, "id-1" can't be assigned to `never`
```

Here the [playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAkgJlAvFARASzgWgIwqgH1Q0wCY9D0sBmFAbgCh7RIoAhAVzQBs4IAnADwAVAHxIoAb3pQoAMwD28gTCgQAHsAgA7OAGcoogBQYAXLACUZjt16CAomoDGXdr2EAaWCJEMAvg3pHeS1dYCgAI04efnEpGQUlIVUNbT1YOBFjODMhSzYo2wEHZ1cIZThPUTE4mSggkPkuCAA6LnkAc0MAAwBZECgMKAASCQxfLvMGWqg+CGB2Pi0oYAALNF0pqF93en9GSJt+ZoTDShwUc2PFU+IyS5Ozmkn6IA) for this